# CodeIgniter: Form validation callback always returns False

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form with some complex rules to process; for example, I must validate two datse which are splitted in three fields (day, month, year), and I must check that the first one is before the second one.

Here is my controller:

```php
public function booking($data, $lang, $page)
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->helper('custom_form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '<br />');

    $data['captcha'] = form_captcha();
    $this->session->captcha = $data['captcha']['word'];

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_place', 'Place', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_nbPeople', 'Number of people', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dateArrivalDay', '', 'callback_form_checkArrivalDate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dateDepartureDay', '', 'callback_form_checkDepartureDate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dateArrivalDay', '', 'callback_form_checkDateConsistency');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_phone', '', 'callback_form_checkEmailOrPhone');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_captcha', '', 'callback_form_checkCaptcha');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view($lang.'/'.$page, $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view($lang.'/'.$page.'-success', $data);

    }
}
```

Here is my `helpers/custom_form_helper.php` file:

```php
function form_checkArrivalDate()
{
    $d = intval($this->input->post('form_dateArrivalDay'));
    $m = intval($this->input->post('form_dateArrivalMonth'));
    $y = intval($this->input->post('form_dateArrivalYear'));

    return(checkdate($m, $d, $y));
}

function form_checkDepartureDate()
{
    $d = intval($this->input->post('form_dateDepartureDay'));
    $m = intval($this->input->post('form_dateDepartureMonth'));
    $y = intval($this->input->post('form_dateDepartureYear'));

    return(checkdate($m, $d, $y));
}

function form_checkDateConsistency()
{
    $da = intval($this->input->post('form_dateArrivalDay'));
    $ma = intval($this->input->post('form_dateArrivalMonth'));
    $ya = intval($this->input->post('form_dateArrivalYear'));

    $dp = intval($this->input->post('form_dateDepartureDay'));
    $mp = intval($this->input->post('form_dateDepartureMonth'));
    $yp = intval($this->input->post('form_dateDepartureYear'));

    $a = mktime(0, 0, 0, $ma, $da, $ya);
    $p = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mp, $dp, $yp);

    return($a < $p);
}
```

Whatever I put in the field "form_dateArrivalDay" and the others, the verifications always fails. Other validators which do not rely on custom callbacks do not have this problem.

If I take out the field name from `set_rules` (first parameter), the validation always passes.

Is there something I'm missing out?

Comment: on a first glance I see you call the rule `form_dateArrivalDay` twice in your controller. One field one rule

Comment: Yeah, that's because I need to perform two checks on the fields. I agree that putting two callbacks in the same rule would be better, but does changing that would correct the initial problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if someone wants to know the answer, I'm saying how I solved my own problem.

There were several mistakes made with that code.

First one is because my callback functions, like `form_checkArrivalDate`, were not in the controller class, but in another file, more precisely in the helper `custom_form_helper.php`. And these functions have to be in the controller class; that's a point the documentation is not precising enough.
If you want your check functions to be found by the validator, you need to drop the `callback_` at the beginning of the name in the `set_rules` function. The function needs to be callable and return TRUE or FALSE depending on the checks.

Second mistake was my POST fields were not visible in my check functions. As the functions are outside of the class, the attribute `$this->input->post` is not herited. To make CodeIgniter's "super object" accessible in a function, you need to add `$CI =& get_instance();` at the beginning of the function, and use the `$CI` object instead of `$this`.

So eventually my controller looks like this (I also added some more things, like the language strings):

```
public function booking($data, $lang, $page)
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->helper('custom_form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '<br />');

    $data['captcha'] = form_captcha();
    $this->session->captcha = $data['captcha']['word'];

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_place', 'Place', 'required', ['required' => $this->lang->line('form_noPlace')]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_nbPeople', 'Number of people', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dateArrivalDay', 'Arrival date', 'required|form_checkArrivalDate|form_checkDateConsistency', ['form_checkArrivalDate' => $this->lang->line('form_incorrectDateArrival'), 'form_checkDateConsistency' => $this->lang->line('form_inconsistentDates')]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dateDepartureDay', 'Departure date', 'required|form_checkDepartureDate', ['form_checkDepartureDate' => $this->lang->line('form_incorrectDateDeparture')]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_phone', 'Phone number', 'form_checkEmailOrPhone', ['form_checkEmailOrPhone' => $this->lang->line('form_incorrectMailOrTel')]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_captcha', 'Captcha', 'form_checkCaptcha', ['form_checkCaptcha' => $this->lang->line('form_incorrectCaptcha')]);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view($lang.'/'.$page, $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view($lang.'/'.$page.'-success', $data);

    }
}
```

And here is my helper:

```
function form_checkArrivalDate()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $d = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateArrivalDay'));
    $m = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateArrivalMonth'));
    $y = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateArrivalYear'));

    return(checkdate($m, $d, $y));
}

function form_checkDepartureDate()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $d = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateDepartureDay'));
    $m = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateDepartureMonth'));
    $y = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateDepartureYear'));

    return(checkdate($m, $d, $y));
}

function form_checkDateConsistency()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $da = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateArrivalDay'));
    $ma = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateArrivalMonth'));
    $ya = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateArrivalYear'));

    $dp = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateDepartureDay'));
    $mp = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateDepartureMonth'));
    $yp = intval($CI->input->post('form_dateDepartureYear'));

    $a = mktime(0, 0, 0, $ma, $da, $ya);
    $p = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mp, $dp, $yp);

    return($a < $p);
}
```

Also, a maybe-unrelated but another problem I ran into is upon the check of two fields - `form_email` and `form_phone`.
I have a field for a phone number, and another one for the email; the user have to fill at least one of the two. So I placed on `form_phone` a function that returns FALSE only if both fields are empty. As one of the two fields can be empty, I did not put a "required" condition.
But this was not working, for some reason it was always returning TRUE, regardless of what was in the fields. The thing is, guess what: if CodeIgniter sees that you did not put the "required" condition, **it does not check other conditions**. Yeah, this is a completely stupid behavior, and I seriously wonder why it was implemented - because, based on what I have seen, it's a clear choice from the devs.

So I had to comment this in form_validation.php library to make my validator work.

```
if (
    ($postdata === NULL OR $postdata === '')
    && $callback === FALSE
    && $callable === FALSE
    && ! in_array($rule, array('required', 'isset', 'matches'), TRUE)
)
{
    continue;
}
```